# goroutines run out of memory UPD: go error handling

Tags: memory, go, goroutine

**UPD**: Turns out, it is a question about error handling in Go

I have written a simple web crawler, that generates the addresses of web-pages on the "main thread", fetches the actual pages in one go-routine and gives the content back via a `chan`, and writes it to a file in another go-routine. However, after about 300,000 iterations of this process, i get the following error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x38 pc=0x22e9]</pre>
```

The error "stacktrace" is quite long, and unfotunately, I don't have it now (I will post it later, after repeating the experiment).

Is there a need to somehow manage the memory, close the channels or something like that?

Below is the code with some omissions.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    channel := make(chan []byte)

    for i:=0; i < 20; i++ {
        go fetcher(generateLink(), channel)
    }

    for a:=0; ; a++ {
        go writeToFile(strconv.Itoa(a), <-channel)
        go fetcher(generateLink(), channel)
        fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(a))
    }
}

func fetcher(url string, channel chan []byte) {

    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        channel <- []byte("")
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    channel <- body
}

func writeToFile(filename string, bytes []byte) {
    ioutil.WriteFile(filename+".html", bytes, 0644)
}

func generateLink() string {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Let's say you start up `godoc` put `return "http://localhost:8080"` as the body of `generateLink()`. Do you still get the failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer deference
```

This means you tried to use a nil pointer. This is a programmer error, not an out of memory error. Since I don't have access to the actual trace or code, there is no way I can help you further.

**Edit:** After taking another look at your code I think I found a possible source of the error.

```
resp, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    channel <- []byte("")
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

You end up referencing `resp` in order to get the field `Body` even when `err != nil`. If `err !=nil`, it is quite likely resp is nil.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The code is pretty actual, the only thing omitted is the link generation. How can I tell where my error is judging by the traces?

Comment: Paste the panic or go to the IRC channel. The backtrace should list the exact line that caused the panic.

Comment: Exactly. OP needs to return after putting the empty byte slice on the channel.

Comment: Yep, thank you all very much. I found the same thing when I actually caught the exception again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only guessing here since I don't have the stacktrace. but the following two lines look suspicious to me:

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
channel <- body
```

How do you know the body is not nil when you send it on the channel? Since writeToFile doesn't check it either it's totally possible that you are tring to write a nil byte slice to the file and it's blowing up there. If you capture an err you should check it before going on.

Comment: Because body is not a pointer, it can't be referenced and cause this type of panic.

Comment: Worst case you get a nil slice which is just empty.

Answer (score 1):

At some point, your call to `http.Get()` fails and returns a non-nil `err`. When this happens, you put an empty byte slice into the channel, but you keep going, and try to read from `resp.Body` anyway, when `resp` is nil.